# MVC Controller Activate and Deactivate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a submit element under an href in a View. I want to activate it and deactivate under the function index() of the controller of this view from a session variable. Is it possible?

```
<a href="/Checkout/AddressAndPayment" input type="submit" data-id="1" role="button" >
    BuyItem
</a>
```

Comment: I'd question your context? Surely you want to either A: Hide the link for those that shouldn't click it, or B: Add an Authorisation attribute on the action method? Also, if you are using MVC why aren't you using the helpers?

Comment: I know but i haven't written this code, but it works fine. I only want to activate or deactivate an input button from the controller

Comment: So you want to disable it based on a session variable?

Comment: Yes from function index of the controller

Comment: You cannot disable an `<a>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only way you can disable the link is within the UI. There are many ways you could do this...

I guess the MVC hack would be to store something in the `ViewBag`. In the controller you can set any variable, for example:

```
ViewBag.CanIClickMyLink = true;
```

Then in the view you can utilise this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Buy Item", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout", null, new { @enabled = ViewBag.CanIClickMyLink })
```

or

```
<a href="@(ViewBag.Enabled ? "https://www.google.co.uk" : "#")">
       BuyItem
</a>
```

Alternatively you can use `Session` to access a property in the user session, this can come with a bit more over head. I hope this helps to get you started, I can always expand my answer.

Personally I would include any important variables such as user Authorisation in the MVC model property. It always feels cleaner and a bit more robust. It is a strongly typed class unlike the dynamic ViewBag. It's very easy for bugs to crop up when using the ViewBag.

Comment: If is more simple to do i can use an input box and not a link

Comment: Your type of Html tag really makes little difference.... I would suggest an `<a>` is the correct choice. Setting `Enabled` to false should disable the on click functionality.

Comment: Very true, In that case I would simple change the `Href` to a '#', I'll update my answer. You could then style it appropriately.